Automate Linux installation
For cloud environments, there is Cloudinit.
I would like to know if there is something similar for desktop systems.
Context: I want to create a kiosk with Chromium pre-installed and running through systemd at boot.
Thank you.

Why not use ChromiomOS, IE a Chromebook @ a kiosk

Cloudinit isn't restricted to the cloud. For example, the Ubuntu raspberry pi images use it

the correct name of the software is Cloud-init, not Cloudinit

Oh, nice! Thank you!
